# Laravel - How to create a settings page for registered user

Tags: laravel

I need to create a settings page when user register my site. Can I make it with register controller and user model or do I need a seperate model/table for this. What I tried is,

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'title' => 'Your website title',
            'analytics' => 'Your google analytics code here',
            'adsense' => 'Your google adsense code here'
        ]);
    }
```

and in setting controller I use only edit and update route. But when user register I get error message that field title dont have any value.

I also tried in route `Route::post('/register', 'SettingsController@store');` and in settings controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find(id, $user_id)->get();
        $user->title = 'Your website title';
        $user->analytics = 'Your google analytics code here';
        $user->adsense = 'Your google adsense code here';
        $user->save(); 
    }
```

Now when register user go to login page. What is the right approach to create a settings page when user register?

Comment: you make quite a mess using the register word again and again. you have added three more fields (`title`, `analytics`, `adsense`) to the `users` table and you are calling them settings. right??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes

Comment: then why don't you add those fields in the register form??